# Why has the delete function disappeared from my Gmail app?

Tags: gmail

I cannot see a delete function on my Gmail account for my inbox.

I have a Galaxy smartphone.

Answer (score 4):

This post should (or might) help: [GMail's delete button is not gone, it's just hiding.](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/06/05/psa-your-gmails-delete-button-is-not-gone-in-the-new-app-its-just-hiding-heres-how-to-re-enable-it/)

**Edit:**
As per the URL, follow the steps below:

- Hit the menu button, and go to settings. Then, go to general settings. You should see the option below at the top of the list - Archive & delete actions. Right now, it should be set to "Show archive only"
- Tap it, and you get three options - Archive only, Delete only, and Archive & Delete. The third option gets rid of the 'Move to Folder' action. Choose the one you want (probably the second or third), and you're set to go - your little trash icon will return.

Note: If you still want to swipe to delete, you must select 'delete only' from the actions menu above.